# Powershell - Regex date range replace

Tags: regex, date, powershell, range

I have an input file which contains some start dates and if those dates are before a specific date `1995-01-01` (YYYY-MM-DD format) then replace the date with the minimum value e.g.

```
<StartDate>1970-12-23</StartDate>
```

would be changed to

```
<StartDate>1995-01-01</StartDate>
```

`<StartDate>1996-05-12</StartDate>` is ok and would remain unchanged.

I was hoping to use regex replace but checking for the date range isn't working as expected. I was hoping to use something like this for the range check

```
\b(?:1900-01-(?:3[01]|2[1-31])|1995/01/01)\b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like `'<StartDate>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})</StartDate>'` to match `<StartDate>`, 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-`, 2 digits, and `</StartDate>`, and then use a callback method to parse the captured into group 1 date and use Martin's code there to compare dates. If the date is before the one defined, use the min date, else, use the one captured.

```
$callback = {
  param($match)
  $current = [DateTime]$match.Groups[1].Value
  $minimum = [DateTime]'1995-01-01'

  if ($minimum -gt $current)
  {
    '<StartDate>1995-01-01</StartDate>'
  }
  else {
    '<StartDate>' + $match.Groups[1].Value + '</StartDate>'
  }
}

$text = '<StartDate>1970-12-23</StartDate>'
$rex = [regex]'<StartDate>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})</StartDate>'
$rex.Replace($text, $callback)
```

[image]

To use it with `Get-Content` and `Foreach-Object`, you may define the `$callback` as above and use

```
$rex = [regex]'<StartDate>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})</StartDate>'
(Get-Content $path\$xml_in) | ForEach-Object {$rex.Replace($_, $callback)} | Set-Content $path\$outfile
```

Comment: You still need to use the `Regex` object as `-replace` does not support a callback as the replacement. Try `(Get-Content $infile) | ForEach-Object {$rex.Replace($_, $callback)} | Set-Content $outfile`

Comment: I'm pulling this in a from a file with multiple lines so can I do it using a get-Content and Foreach-object (assuming that $_ is the variable for the current line)

(Get-Content $path\$xml_out) | Foreach-Object {$rex = [regex]'<StartDate>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{\}<\StartDate>', $rex.Replace($_, $callback)} | set-content $path\$xml_out

Comment: You should not assign any `$rex` inside `Foreach-Object`. Assign `$rex` before it and only once, and use it as I showed above (I tested it in my Powershell in Win7, and it worked).

Comment: Thanks to all that helped especially Wiktor.

$xml_in="sample2.xml"
$outfile="output.xml"

$callback = {
  param($match)
  $current = [DateTime]$match.Groups[1].Value
  $minimum = [DateTime]'1995-01-01'

  if ($minimum -gt $current)
  {
    '<StartDate>1995-01-01</StartDate>'
  }
  else {
    '<StartDate>' + $match.Groups[1].Value + '</StartDate>'
  }
}

$rex = [regex]'<StartDate>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})</StartDate>'
#$rex = [regex]'<StartDate>(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{\})'
(Get-Content $path\$xml_in) | ForEach-Object {$rex.Replace($_, $callback)} | Set-Content $path\$outfile

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `regex` here. Just cast the dates to `DateTime` and compare them:

```
$currentDate = [DateTime]'1970-12-23'
$minDate = [DateTime]'1995-01-01'

if ($minDate -gt $currentDate)
{
    $currentDate = $minDate
}
```

Comment: It's not only about the date. The OP should not use regex for the XML parsing, either. Powershell has built-in XML capabilities, it isn't even especially hard to do this properly.